# Java .split - remove the first occurrence

Tags: java, regex, string, split

How do I use .split() so that the first occurrence of the regex is also removed?

Example:

```
String a = "   a       b  cdef  g "
a.split("\\s+");
```

Gives me:

```
{"", "a", "b", "cdef", "g"}
```

Is there a way to remove the first element ("") without doing it separately? And why does this happen?

Comment: Can you `trim()` the String before using `split`?

Comment: Yeah, didn't think about that, thanks for that. But how does the split() method work so that the first element of the array becomes an empty string?

Comment: _"When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array."_ So that's why you get empty String.

Comment: You can split according to space that is preceded by `\w`: `.split("(?<=\\w)\\s+"))` - this will return a with the spaces before it (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you can trim the `String` before splitting:

```
 a.trim().split("\\s+");
```

This will give you `{"a", "b", "cdef", "g"}`